# State doesn't change after fetching data in React context API

Tags: reactjs, state, react-context

I'm new to context API i tried a simple case with it and it worked as well, now i cant set the state to my context API provider after fetching data from an endpoint but it doesn't change!

Here is my code:

```
export const SignalementContext = new createContext();
class SignalementContextProvider extends Component {
state = {
  signalements: []
};

componentDidMount() {
  this.loadSignalement();
}
loadSignalement() {
  Object.assign(axios.defaults, { headers: { accept: "application/json" } });
  axios
    .get("http://localhost:3005/signalements")
    .then(res => {
      console.log("hani huni" + res.data);
      const signalements = res.data;
      this.setState({ signalements: signalements });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      if (error.response) {
        alert(
          "Code: " +
            error.response.data.error.code +
            "\r\nMessage: " +
            error.response.data.error.message
        );
      } else {
        console.log("Error", error.message);
      }
    });
}
fetch = async () => {};
render() {
  return (
    <SignalementContext.Provider value={{ ...this.state }}>
      {this.props.children}
    </SignalementContext.Provider>
  );
}
}

export default SignalementContextProvider;
```

Comment: is signalements an array or a object?

Comment: signalements is an array!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, although:

- You don't want to spread state into new object. That context value will be new on every render and you don't want that, better to write it like `value={this.state}`
- You should export just Consumer from `SignalementContext`, because you are implementing your own provider via `SignalementContextProvider`

Are you sure your code in `loadSignalement` will not catch?

Comment: yes i will not catch i'm sure , could it be an "callback hell " problem because i'm consuming this provider in anotther component!